# How can I add a new Entry field with a Button? The Entry field was created by a loop in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

[image]

I created entry columns and I want to add new columns by button clicking. The problem is I created the columns by a for loop. I don't know how I should touch the original loop with the function.

My code is looks like this:

```
list = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6', 'Label7', 'Label8', 'Label9']

def some_def():
    myEntry_loop.grid(row=j, column=k + 1)

for j in range(len(list)):
    for k in range(3):
        myLab = Label(root, text=list[j])
        myLab.grid(row=j, column=0, sticky=E)
        myEntry_loop = Entry(root)
        myEntry_loop.grid(row=j, column=k + 1, pady=10, padx=10)

myButton = Button(root, text="Add New Filed", command=some_def)
myButton.grid(row=10, column=4)
```

Comment: You want all those labels created with a single button click ? Or only 1 at a button click

Comment: I want to create entry boxes in a new column only clicking once the button

Comment: Ok you mean you want it to display the name of the label only. And when you click button, all of the entry boxes should appear

Comment: Forget labels it's not important. They just specify the number of the rows. There is a button. I want that if I click it, it will add a new entry column. I added a print screen, oerhaps it will help to get what i want.

Comment: I have posted an answer, please accept if that works

Comment: It's working. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I'd like to highlight you should not use variable name as reserved words like `list`
Now, coming to your requirement. Here's what I wrote

```
li = ['Label1', 'Label2', 'Label3', 'Label4', 'Label5', 'Label6', 'Label7', 'Label8', 'Label9']
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
col=4
def some_def():
    global col
    for j in range(len(li)):
        myEntry_loop = Entry(root)
        myEntry_loop.grid(row=j, column=col, pady=10, padx=10)
    col+=1
            

for j in range(len(li)):
    myLab = Label(root, text=li[j])
    myLab.grid(row=j, column=0, sticky=E)
    for k in range(3):
        myEntry_loop = Entry(root)
        myEntry_loop.grid(row=j, column=k + 1, pady=10, padx=10)

myButton = Button(root, text="Add New Filed", command=some_def)
myButton.grid(row=10, column=4)
```

On every button click new column is being created. Since you have used the same name of entry widget in your for loop I have used it like that only. You should know that you wont be able to use methods like get() if you want to extract the content since you have defined all the widgets to be of same name.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you would need to define a current value for the y axis. Also， I don't really understand the use of the "list". I would recommend to just create a y axis, then just grid the new entry at that y axis.

But talking about your current code, the I don't see where you have defined the variable j and k, and you also need to increase k by one each time, not just saying k+1.